What can I substitute for cream of tartar in mock apple pie?
Basically what the title says.
The recipe is here: https://www.allrecipes.com/recipe/9545/mock-apple-pie/
I don’t know enough about food science to know what purpose the cream of tartar is supposed to do in this recipe in particular so I don’t know what to replace it with without making it taste bad.
Also, out of curiosity, what is the cream of tartar doing in this recipe, if not acting as a leavening agent?
I’d appreciate any insight, thank you so much.

Cream of tartar (Postassium bitartrate) is a salt of tartaric acid, so it's presumably providing the acidity to further the illusion that it tastes like apples.
I'd substitute a nice tart apple, myself, but I'm not exactly committed to "mock" when it comes to apple pie. Vinegar or lemon juice or citric acid would probably contribute too much of their own flavor to work, at a guess.

I know someone who dearly loves apples but developed an apple allergy later in life. Mock apple pie (if it tastes anywhere near the real thing) would probably be something they’d be interested in.

I see. In the recipe linked within the post there is lemon juice in addition to the cream of tartar. I can appreciate having real apple pie, this is more an experiment than anything else and I do not have access to cream of tartar. Thank you for the explanation about cream of tartar, I appreciate the information.

@legendaryramen Any substitutions to a recipe like this are likely to wildly change the flavor. As an experiment, this will not yield useful data. If you don't have access to cream of tartar, you should find another recipe.
